# Annoying phantom dot

Tags: modeling

I am new at 3d and wanted to make simple room with Blender, but got a very annoying problem - a dot above my object which I can't remove but at render it's reflecting light very much :(

[image: Normal view]

[image: With out selection]

[image: Editor mode]

[image: Render]

Comment: in OBJECT mode  Alt+H to unhide all objects then look for this dot

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was particle :)

Comment: @SiarheiK Go ahead and add that as an answer (In detail!) so this can come off the unanswered list. I can post it instead if you want

Comment: As SiarheiK mentioned, it would be great if you could post an answer detailing what you did to fix the issue. That way your question can be removed from the list of unanswered questions and future visitors with the same issue can fix it themselves.